# How to get text from Facebook comments plugin with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I am trying to get Facebook comments from the news site's comments plugin. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
import facebook
token = #valid token
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version='2.10')
url = "http://www.jutarnji.hr/6703059"
url_id = graph.get_object(url)['og_object']['id']
comments = graph.get_connections(url_id, 'comments')
```

And this is the (unwanted) output:

`{'data': []}`

Comment: That used to work via the `comments` sub field of the `og_object`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008, but https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/url doesn’t mention this any more. Not sure if they removed this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
import facebook    #sudo pip install facebook-sdk
import itertools
import json
import re
import requests

access_token = "XXX"
user = 'leehsienloong'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')

Jstr = json.dumps(posts)
JDict = json.loads(Jstr)

count = 0
for i in JDict['data']:
    allID = i['id']
    try:
        allComments = i['comments']

        for a in allComments['data']:  
            count += 1
            print a['message']


    except (UnicodeEncodeError):
        pass


print count
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code produces KeyError: 'comments', and I can't clearly see how to apply it to specific external URL.